# Validation of objects inside array of jsonb objects with RubyOnRails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, validation, jsonb

How would you validate each object inside an array of object with Rails?

I am building a user profile form in our Rails app. Inside user model, we have basic string attributes but some jsonb fields as well. JSONb fields default to `[]` because we want to store an array of objects inside that attribute. Here is an example of simplified user model attributes:

- `name: string`
- `email: string`
- `education: jsonb, default: []`

Education is an array of objects such as:

```
[{
  school: 'Harvard university',
  degree: 'Computer Science',
  from_date: 'Tue, 11 Jul 2017 16:22:12 +0200`,
  to_date: 'Tue, 11 Jul 2017 16:22:12 +0200'
},{
  school: 'High school',
  degree: 'Whatever',
  from_date: 'Tue, 11 Jul 2017 16:22:12 +0200`,
  to_date: 'Tue, 11 Jul 2017 16:22:12 +0200'
}]
```

User should be able to click <kbd>Add school</kbd> button, to add more fields via jquery. That jquery part is not important for this question - maybe just an explanation why we used an Array of objects.

How would you validate each item in education array, so I can mark the text field containing validtion error with red color? I got adviced that using FormObject pattern might help here. I have also tried writing custom validator that inherits from `ActiveModel::Validator` class, but the main problem still lies in fact, that I am dealing with an array, not actual object..

Thanks for any constructive help.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could treat education records as first-class citizens in your Rails model layer by introducing a non-database backed `ActiveModel` model class for them:

```
class Education
  include ActiveModel::Model

  attr_accessor :school, :degree, :from_date, :to_date

  validates :school, presence: true
  validates :degree, presence: true

  def initialize(**attrs)
    attrs.each do |attr, value|
      send("#{attr}=", value)
    end
  end

  def attributes
    [:school, :degree, :from_date, :to_date].inject({}) do |hash, attr|
      hash[attr] = send(attr)
      hash
    end
  end

  class ArraySerializer
    class << self
      def load(arr)
        arr.map do |item|
          Education.new(item)
        end
      end

      def dump(arr)
        arr.map(&:attributes)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Then you can transparently serialize and deserialize the `education` array in your `User` model:

```
class User
   # ...
   serialize :education, Education::ArraySerializer
   # ...
end
```

This solution should allow you to validate individual attributes of  `Education` objects with built-in Rails validators, embed them in a nested form, and so on.

**Important:** I wrote the code above without testing it, so it might need a few modifications.

Comment: How would this be embedded as nested fields in parent model? Adding just accepts_nested_attributes_for does not work @solymo.si

Answer (score 2):

Something like this perhaps? (probably you'll want the hash to be passed with keys as strings and not symbols and then verified for item[string] not item[symbol]

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  validates :education, evalidation: true

  class EvalidationValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
    def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
      record.errors[attribute] << "must be a valid array & json" unless (check_json_array(value) rescue nil)
    end
  end

  def check_json_array(value)
     return false unless value.is_a?(Array)
     value.each do |item|
       return false unless item.is_a?(Hash)
       return false if item[:school].blank? || item[:degree].blank? || !valid_date_time(item[:from_date]) || !valid_date_time(item[:to_date])
     end
     true
  end

  def valid_date_time(date)
     #this needs work as it will pass for instance "Tue" as true, since DateTime will parse even single day initials to the current closest date
    (DateTime.parse(date) rescue nil)
  end
end
```